# CMS Made Simple .htaccess WWW Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a CMS Made Simple website with pretty URLs enabled. I would like to redirect all non-WWW traffic to the WWW url but cannot appear to do this without being redirected to the WWW version of the site but without pretty urls.

For example I access `example.com/my-page` and get redirected to `www.example.com/index.php?page=my-page`. Really I want to be redirected to `www.example.com/my-page`.

My current .htaccess file contains this:

```
# Attempt to override some php settings, these settings may be helpful on some hosts if your
# default configuration does not meet CMS's minimum requirements, and your host
# has given your account appropriate permissions
#php_value upload_max_filesize "10M"
#php_value session_save_path "tmp/cache"

#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
#php_flag register_globals Off
#php_flag session.use_trans_sid Off

# (this is important, so uncomment if your host permit)
#Options -Indexes
#ServerSignature Off

#Options +FollowSymLinks

# To prevent E_STRICT problems with PHP 5.3+ you can uncomment the following lines
# Note: These settings should only be enabled for production sites!
#php_flag display_startup_errors 0
#php_flag display_errors 0
#php_flag html_errors 0
#php_value docref_root 0
#php_value docref_ext 0

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#
#Sub-dir e.g: /cmsms
RewriteBase /

# 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
# include a trailing slash
# but ignore POST requests.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
# but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_header.c>
# Disable ETags
Header unset ETag
FileEtag None
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress css, plaintext, xml, gif, and images in transport.
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/plain text/xml image/gif image/jpeg image/png
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
# Set expires tags on various files... so that the browser wont attempt to reload them.
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
<IfModule mod_header.c>
  # Setting cache control to public allowes proxy servers to cache the items too.
  Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas how to redirect to the WWW site while keeping the pretty URLs?

Comment: What problem are you having? FYI, the www redirect rule needs to be one of the first rules in the .htaccess file not the last. Move it to the top above the other rewrite for pretty urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your WWW redirect rule to before the pretty URL redirect (easier to just move to the top of file).

The reason is actually occurs the way you observed is that it redirect the pretty URL first (the `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]`) And since that rules doesn't have [L] (i.e. not `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`), it falls through and hit your WWW redirect with rewritten URL, so you got redirect to URL without pretty URL as you observed. Add L won't be sufficient also because it would also hit the pretty URL rule first.